# Platform developer 1 certificate

Tags: certification, platform-developer-1

I have doubt about Platform developer 1 certificate. If I attempt the Platform developer 1 certificate exam in next one week(with in 25th, October 2018), then which Salesforce version questions does I am gonna face?

Does i will get question about summer'18 only or Is there any chance to get winter'19 release questions also(Because, as every one knows that recently we updated to winter'19).
Even I gone through the [salesforce webassessor](https://webassessor.com/wa.do?page=publicHome&branding=SALESFORCE) site, but I am getting little over there.

please some valued suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still get Summer'18 questions as the Certifications do not instantly flip over onto the latest version immediately on release.

Your exam registration will show the release short code in it so you will know which version you have to prepare for.

For example when I go to Webassessor to book an exam it shows me only SU18 - Summer 18 as an option.

[image: Webassessor PD Booking]

Comment: Thanks Dave. I actually do not register for web assessor, that is why I got confusion. Now its clear for me.

Comment: Dave, one more question from me, Do you any idea when the salesoforce is going to conduct Winter'19 exam?

Comment: Kumaar I don't know that as the SF certification team will release the updated exam when it is ready.